# Jquery Accordion Selector Issue

Tags: jquery, accordion

Any idea why this accordion isn't working correctly? Only the clicked division should open/close but instead a whole series of divisions are opening/closing.

http://jsfiddle.net/QtvcB/7/

I'm not so good with jquery selectors. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the parent `li` then find its `.accordion`:

http://jsfiddle.net/QtvcB/8/

```
var selectedAccordion = $(this).closest("li").find(".accordion").slideDown();
$(".accordion").not(selectedAccordion).slideUp();
```